# CSS gradient fill text in :before on separate line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to create a "5-star rating", but need the stars to be on the line before the text. My starting point is the last of the 5 methods in [Five Methods for Five-Star Ratings](https://css-tricks.com/five-methods-for-five-star-ratings/) on CSS Tricks. Basically, it assigns a rating number as a CSS variable, then uses that to calculate a gradient fill on the stars, which are unicode characters in a `:before` tag.

The problem is, I need the stars to be on a separate line from the main text.

He has the whole div set to `display: inline-block`:

```
:root {
  --star-color: #fff;
  --star-background: #fc0;
}

.Stars {
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
  
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  
  &::before {
    content: '★★★★★';
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="stars" style="--rating: 2.3;"></div>
```

Various things I've tried to get the stars on their own line:

- Change the `:before` to `display: block`
- Change the `:before` to `display: block; background-size: 100%`
- Change the `<div>` to `display: flex; flex-direction: column`
- Add the '\A' escape character to the `:before` `content`

All of the above result in the background not aligning with the star-text in various different ways, the most interesting being when the text is centered, which is my actual use case.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Snippet:

```css
:root {
  --star-color: #fff;
  --star-background: #fc0;
}

.Stars {
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
  
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.Stars:before {
    content: '★★★★★';
    
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.two-line:before {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Working</h1>
<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 4;">4 stars!</div>

<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 2.5;">2.5 stars. Meh.</div>

<div class="Stars" style="--rating: 1.5;">1.5 stars. Doh!</div>

<div class="Stars centered" style="--rating: 4;">4 stars!</div>

<div class="Stars centered" style="--rating: 2.5;">2.5 stars. Meh.</div>

<div class="Stars centered" style="--rating: 1.5;">1.5 stars. Doh!</div>

<h1>Not Working</h1>
<div class="Stars two-line" style="--rating: 4;">4 stars!</div>

<div class="Stars two-line" style="--rating: 2.5;">2.5 stars. Meh.</div>

<div class="Stars two-line" style="--rating: 1.5;">1.5 stars. Doh!</div>

<div class="Stars centered two-line" style="--rating: 4;">4 stars!</div>

<div class="Stars centered two-line" style="--rating: 2.5;">2.5 stars. Meh.</div>

<div class="Stars centered two-line" style="--rating: 1.5;">1.5 stars. Doh!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this style!

```
.two-line:before {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: But then it's _inline_, not on a separate line.